# Confusion on Proof of Gram-Schmidt Conjugation Process in context of Conjugate Gradient Method

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, machine-learning, gram-schmidt

First of all, I'd like to make clear that I'm talking about the Gram-Schmidt *Conjugation* process (in the context of conjugate gradient method for optimization), which instead of making a set of *n* independent vectors orthonormal, makes a set of *n* independent vectors conjugates - that is: expressable in the form

[image]

(where vector u_i and vector u_j are conjugates, or sometimes, "A-orthogonal").

Understandably, this formula is going to be very similar to Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization, since the process is the same - but instead of projecting (and subtracting) some vector v onto all the previous orthogonal vectors and subtracting, we're projecting on to the all the previous conjugate vectors and subtracting.

So, the question is what this "projection matrix" is. [In the paper/explanation](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Equake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf) I'm working through to understand Conjugate Gradient, there is two pages dedicated to the explanation of Gram-Schmidt Conjugation Process (pages 31-32 in pdf) and there is a proof of what the "projection" matrix is, but I don't understand it. I recommend you look at it in the paper but here is a screenshot:

[image]

I get equation (36), but kind of get lost after that. I get why they're premultiplying, since the whole definition of conjugate is that they abide to that property of u_i(T) * A*u_j = 0, but I really don't get the new subscript "j" which I haven't seen before and the removal of the summation.

If someone could explain it step by step that would be really good,

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal is to find $\beta_{ij}$ such that $d_{(i)}^TAd_{(j)}=0$.

We transpose equation $(36)$ and premultiply it to $Ad_{(j)}$

In the very next line, the summation seems to vanish, that is because if $k \ne j$, then $d_{(k)}^TAd_{(j)}=0$. Hence only one term is left.

After which, we can solve for $\beta_{ij}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's quite beautiful how it all goes together. Tried it out on the whiteboard and made so much sense... thanks.

Comment: oh! Also was wondering how you were able to transpose the vectors inside the summation when you transposed both sides of the equation.

Comment: we have $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$ isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering since there is a multiplication within the summation (the B_ij matrix and the d_k vector) we transpose both of these at the same time $$\left( \beta _{ij}d_{j}\right) ^{T}=d_{j}^{T}\beta _{ij}^{T}$$ - why in the equation did they not switch order? Does the B matrix not have a tranpose since we assume it is symmetric?

Comment: $\beta_{i,j}$ is a scalar